How to use VercelAI and Google GenAI for sending streaming reponse from Express backend to React Frontend?
I am developing an application with React frontend and Express backend for text generation and further multi-turn chat using Google GenerativeAI, GeminiAPI and Vercel AI SDK following their documentation.
I am unable to figure out the suitable way to implement, generating streaming response and use in the frontend using the vercel AI and google genai.
(if possible, without using Node - EventStreams)
There are different versions provided for Generating Streaming Response, tried many versions following the documentation here
I tried the NextJs version as well with returning new StreamingResponse(), but didn't work.
Frontend component:
import { Send } from "lucide-react";
import { useChat } from "ai/react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const { messages, input, handleInputChange, handleSubmit } = useChat({
    api: "http://localhost:3001/api/genai",
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(messages);
  }, [messages]);

  return (
    <div className="mt-2 flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center p-12">
      <form
        onSubmit={(event) => {
          event.preventDefault();

          handleSubmit(event, {
            // additional data : input by user
            data: { prompt: input },
          });
        }}
        className="w-full h-full flex flex-row items-center gap-2"
      >
        <input
          type="text"
          value={input}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          placeholder="ask something"
          className="border-b border-dashed outline-none w-full px-4 py-4 placeholder:text-sky-600 focus:placeholder-transparent"
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="rounded-full shadow-md border flex flex-row"
        >
          <Send className="stroke-stone-500 p-3 h-10 w-10" />
        </button>
      </form>

      {/* Messages */}
      {/* {JSON.stringify(messages)} */}
      <div className="flex flex-col-reverse w-full text-black text-left mt-4 gap-4 whitespace-pre-wrap">
        {messages.map((m, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i} className="p-4 shadow-md rounded-md">
              {m?.content}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const Form = () => {
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      className="w-full h-full flex flex-row items-center gap-2"
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="ask something"
        className="border-b border-dashed outline-none w-full px-4 py-4 placeholder:text-sky-600 focus:placeholder-transparent"
      />
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="rounded-full shadow-md border flex flex-row"
      >
        <Send className="stroke-stone-500 p-3 h-10 w-10" />
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default App;


Express Backend
import { GoogleGenerativeAI } from "@google/generative-ai";
import { createStreamableValue } from "ai/rsc";
import { streamText } from "ai";
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";

dotenv.config();

const PORT = 3001;
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY);

app.post("/api/genai", async (req, res) => {
  const stream = createStreamableValue("");

  (async () => {
    // const { textStream } = await streamText({
    //   model: openai("gpt-3.5-turbo"),
    //   prompt: input,
    // });
    const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-1.5-flash" });
    const result = await model.generateContentStream(req.body.data.prompt);

    for await (const delta of result.stream) {
      stream.update(delta);
    }

    stream.done();
  })();

  return { output: stream.value };
});

// {
//   const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-1.5-flash" });
//   const result = await model.generateContentStream(req.body.data.prompt);
// const response = await result.response;
// const text = response.text();

// res.writeHead(200, {
//   "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
//   "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
//   Connection: "keep-alive",
// });

// let text = "";
// let index = 0;
// for await (const chunk of result.stream) {
//   const chunkText = chunk.text();
//   console.log(index + " " + chunkText);
//   text += chunkText;
//   index++;
//   res.write(`data: ${chunkText}\n\n`);
// }

// res.end();
// }

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});


